# MySQL Pivot and Left Join

Tags: mysql, left-join, pivot-table

Product

| prod_id | prod_name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Orange |
| 11 | Apple |
| 12 | Carrot |
| 13 | Lettuce |

Category

| cat_id | cat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Fruit |
| 21 | Vegetable |

Item

| item_id | property_type | property_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | fk_prod_id | 10 |
| 30 | fk_cat_id | 20 |
| 31 | fk_prod_id | 11 |
| 31 | fk_cat_id | 20 |
| 32 | fk_prod_id | 12 |
| 32 | fk_cat_id | 21 |

I am trying to pivot Item then left join with Product and Category to get:

| item_id | fk_prod_id | fk_cat_id | prod_name | cat_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 10 | 20 | Orange | Fruit |
| 31 | 11 | 20 | Apple | Fruit |
| 32 | 12 | 21 | Carrot | Vegetable |

Unfortunately:

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN property_type = 'fk_prod_id' THEN property_value END) AS fk_prod_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN property_type = 'fk_cat_id' THEN property_value END) AS fk_cat_id
FROM item AS i
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON p.prod_id = fk_prod_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = fk_cat_id
GROUP BY item_id;
```

`#Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fk_prod_id' in 'on clause'`

How do I left join other table(s) after a pivot table for the above scenario?

Comment: Select is done last, the rows with that column name don't exist until after the from/where/etc.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(item_id, property_type)` is defined as UNIQUE (which is reasonable) then joining 2 Item tables copies is more simple and maybe even more fast:

```sql
SELECT item_id, 
       i1.property_value fk_prod_id, 
       i2.property_value fk_cat_id, 
       p.prod_name, 
       c.cat_name
FROM Item i1
JOIN Item i2 USING (item_id)
JOIN Product p ON p.prod_id = i1.property_value
JOIN Category c ON c.cat_id = i2.property_value
WHERE i1.property_type = 'fk_prod_id'
  AND i2.property_type = 'fk_cat_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    fk_prod_id,
    fk_cat_id,
    prod_name,
    cat_name
FROM (
    SELECT
        item_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN property_type = 'fk_prod_id' THEN property_value END) AS fk_prod_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN property_type = 'fk_cat_id' THEN property_value END) AS fk_cat_id
    FROM item AS i
    GROUP BY item_id
) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON p.prod_id = t1.fk_prod_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = t1.fk_cat_id;
```

Comment: In other words, do exactly what your prose said, "pivot Item then left join with Product and Category". PS Code-only answers are poor. Better is to explain why/how a post answers the question and/or what the problem was. [answer]